# How can a non-constant function over the p-adic numbers have a derviative of zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This question came to mind after reading the following fact:

"In calculus over the p-adic numbers, a function can have derivative zero without being constant."

I never heard about p-adic numbers before so I started digging and I didn't really find out anything that would make them act like a variable instead of a number, can someone explain this please?

Comment: I'm not sure what the last paragraph means. Care to explain?

Comment: It could be *locally constant*. Recall $\Bbb Q_p$ is not connected; indeed it is totally disconnected.

Comment: functions with values in what?

Comment: Where did you read it from?

Comment: That is the main fact source: https://twitter.com/AnalysisFact/status/1260230886131404800
This page is usually pretty trust worthy and followed by the likes of field medalist Timothy Gowers, etc...

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that even over the reals, there are plenty of non-constant functions with zero derivative: Zero derivative means *locally* constant, and if the function's domain is not connected, of course $f$ might be "constantly" $1$ somewhere and "constantly" $17$ somewhere else. One big difference between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ is that in the latter, no set except singletons are connected, wheres e.g. $\mathbb R$ itself and its popular subsets, the intervals, are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, consider the function $f$ on $p$-adic numbers defined by $f\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i p^i\right) = x_0$.  Then $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$, but $f$ is not constant.